# How to read and display file in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to read and display the contents of file in a chrome extension (The file is already inside the extension directory).How do it?Whether I can use HTML5 to read it?

```
  var elema3 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("slicefooter");
  elema3[0].innerHTML='Shanmuga Subramanian';

  var a1=chrome.extension.getURL('script1.txt');
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(a1);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use XMLHttpRequest.

Example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('script1.txt'), true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        //... The content has been read in xhr.responseText
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to store the contents of your text in your HTML itself using something like

`<script id="textFile" type="text/x-template">...</script>`

and then reference the contents of the template via `document.getElementById('textFile')`.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: this is not applicable to chrome extensions

Comment: It totally does, in fact I should have thought of this before!